# Can big numbers be imported as Text in Excel from Google Sheets with QueryTables.Add?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to import a table from Google Sheets into Excel with VBA. The table contains barcode information so the numbers need to be presented without any changes. I cannot find a way to insert the values as text, and the `WebFormatting = xlNone` command doesn't prevent the inserted table from overwriting the cell format onto which it is inserted. Eventually, the values are pasted as "General" form, and Excel shortens them.

The table is in the following link and the formatting needs to be such as this:

[Google Sheets table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19z0-gYw645ns1V5nUwW5eUu0xwq5PJOu84TShSv8OPM/edit?usp=sharing)

I tried a couple of ways.

**Importing as URL:**

```
Sub Import_Data()

 Cells.Clear
 
 Dim conn As String
 Dim qt As QueryTable
 conn = "URL;https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19z0-gYw645ns1V5nUwW5eUu0xwq5PJOu84TShSv8OPM/edit?usp=sharing"
 Set qt = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=conn, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
 
 With qt
        .WebTables = "1"
        .WebFormatting = xlNone
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .Refresh
 End With
End Sub
```

But the result looks like this:

[image]

and I cannot retrieve the digits that are lost due to the formatting, even if I change the format manually afterwards.

**Importing as TEXT:**

```
Sub Import_Data_As_Text()

 Cells.Clear

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19z0-gYw645ns1V5nUwW5eUu0xwq5PJOu84TShSv8OPM/edit?usp=sharing", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    
    
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .FieldNames = False
    .RowNumbers = True
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = False
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = _
 Array(xlDMYFormat, xlTextFormat)
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

   End With
End Sub
```

But the result is a complete mess:
[image]

I would try to clean it up and keep only the columns that matter, but it doesn't even load all the contents of the "Barcode input" column, it stops at the 5th entry and doesn't load it completely, such as so:
`9300001234..."><meta name="google" content="notranslate"><meta http-equiv="X-UA` and goes on loading the Google Sheets code.

Any ideas might be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: for more control: using https://benborgers.com/posts/google-sheets-json you could  get your data as JSON - https://opensheet.elk.sh/19z0-gYw645ns1V5nUwW5eUu0xwq5PJOu84TShSv8OPM/Form%20Responses%201  and parse it using VBA-JSON  - https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you very much for your comment. Parsing it as JSON worked, I am grateful for your assistance.